# Finding a continuous function whose integration over some period satisfies a specific condition

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I need to find a continuous and smooth function $y(x)$ such that it satisfy the following condition: $$\int_0^a x\,y(x)\,dx=a^2\,y(a)$$
Does anyone know of a method to find such function?

Comment: I checked and found that $y(x)=1/x$ is a right answer, though I don't understand how you could find it.

Comment: Differentiate wrt $a$ and get $a y(a)=a^2 y'(a)+2 a y(a)$ that is $y'(a)=-\dfrac{y(a)}{a}$  integrate and get $y(a)= \dfrac{k}{a}$ or $y(x)=\dfrac{k}{x}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming it has to hold for every $a > 0$:

By differentiating both sides of 
$$\int_0^a xy(x)\,dx = a^2 y(a)$$

with respect to $a$ we obtain:

$$ay(a) = 2ay(a)+a^2y'(a)\implies y'(a) = -\frac{2}{a}y(a)$$

We got a differential equation which is separable:

$$\frac{dy}{da} = -\frac{2}{a}y$$
$$\frac{dy}{y} = -\frac{2\,da}{a}$$

By integrating we get $y(x) = \frac{C}{x}$, for some $C \in\mathbb{R}$.

Indeed:

$$\int_0^a x\cdot\frac{C}{x}\,dx = C \int_0^a dx = Ca = a^2\cdot\frac{C}{a}, \quad\forall a > 0$$

Comment: How could you move from $a$ as a variable to $x$ in the last step?

Comment: @KamelIsaac That's because saying $y(a) = \frac{C}{a}, \forall a > 0$ is the same as saying $y(x) = \frac{C}{x}, \forall x > 0$. Your question was to find $y(x)$ so I switched the variable to $x$, although it is ultimately irrelevant.

Comment: I appreciate your help much.